# Detect whether a polygon is well formed or not (Google Map Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, discrete-mathematics

I have now two polygons as in the screen.

The first is "well formed", in a form that contains data (the one in blue) the second one has an intersection and, for that reason, is not well formed and I would like to delete it if it has intersections.

Any idea of how to detect the intersection? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for a java implementation, none found!! :'(

Comment: Do some search to learn about it and then you will know it is very simple see this link : http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~hulber/cgeom/giftWrap.java

Comment: the code suggested never worked. Finally, I end up with this solution: http://pastebin.com/TuCEaYWj